# iOS 7: UINavigationBar not in UINavigationController does not draw translucency correctly

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7, uinavigationbar, ios7.1

I have a UINavigationBar (not in a UINavigationController) in my view hierarchy, but it sometimes does not draw its translucent background correctly. In the image below, I have a navigation bar with **barTintColor = [UIColor redColor]** and content underneath it. For some reason, the left and right sides are transparent. Why is this the case, and how can I fix this? (I also think I'm having more of this after switching to iOS 7.1.)

[image: UINavigationBar problem with UIBackdropView]

Comment: Hi. Do you find any solution? I have the same problem